# Remote touch events to Android (without root)

Tags: android, bluetooth

I have a problem in sending touch events to Android (not to a specific application, system-wide touch events) through bluetooth.

I know that there are similar questions, but I still could not find the solution. I will be really happy if somebody helps me on this issue.

You can find details of my problem below :

**Requirement :**

To send remote touch events to Android (without root) through bluetooth.

**Possible options I discovered so far :**

1) Use of ADB commands - This is possible via USB cable and over network connection; however it is not allowed via bluetooth. Workaround I thought of :

- To write an Android application with a background service which listens for Bluetooth inputs; and once it receives input, it runs ADB commands within the app itself. However, I think this requires rooted Android.

2) MonkeyRunner - I think this is also not possible through bluetooth.

3) Accessibility Service - According to my research, writing an accessibility service may be a solution to simulate touch events **only when specific conditions are met** (e.g. view clicks). But I need to initiate the touch from an external bluetooth device, without waiting for a specific condition.

4) Connecting the external bluetooth device as a HID (e.g. mouse) and simulate the touch on mouse button click. But in this case, the mouse pointer will always be visible to user. I also could not find a way to hide the mouse pointer. There are some tutorials to customise the pointer (e.g. a bigger one), but as I saw transparent mouse pointer is not supported.

I found an application called **AutoInput** (a Tasker plugin), which simulates touch events, but I could not get any feedback about how it works actually, I could not find how it simulates touch events.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Regards

Comment: If what you want is possible outside of the options that you listed, it is a security flaw that needs to be fixed. AutoInput uses accessibility APIs.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. The point that I did not understand is; in the AutoInput descriptive video it says that, "it is possible to toggle Airplane Mode everyday at 1:20 PM". How do they achieve this implementation? There is not any user initiated action; but the AutoInput can automatically open Settings page etc., according to system time. If I can find the way how they are triggering touch action with Accessibility API, I may also use that approach in my case. I just need a way to trigger touch manually instead of according to the system time. Thanks in advance.

Comment: there's a lot other similar question like yours before, and me myself was also finding a way to implement touch without root, however those solutions I found only available to your own app, (even INJECT_EVENT can't help). Take it negatively, if there exists a way to implement this, there should've be apps doing this without root, what I mean is much more people already come up with the same idea before, but something not intended by Android, like CommonsWare said, is a bug or just don't exist.

Comment: I'm assuming you already have a Bluetooth-connected device you can program as well. There would be some setup involved, but once that's done an AccessibilityService should be able to do this. Is this still something you are looking to accomplish?